# CORDOVA FILE PLUGIN Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to write a file using cordova file plugin following example from https://www.neontribe.co.uk/cordova-file-plugin-examples/

And here is my code:

```
var errorHandler = function (fileName, e) {  
        var msg = '';

        switch (e.code) {
            case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                msg = 'Storage quota exceeded';
                break;
            case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                msg = 'File not found';
                break;
            case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                msg = 'Security error';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                msg = 'Invalid modification';
                break;
            case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                msg = 'Invalid state';
                break;
            default:
                msg = 'Unknown error';
                break;
        };

    console.log('Error (' + fileName + '): ' + msg);
}

function writeToFile(fileName, data) {
    data = JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t');
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
        directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                    // for real-world usage, you might consider passing a success callback
                    console.log('Write of file "' + fileName + '"" completed.');
                };

                fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                    // you could hook this up with our global error handler, or pass in an error callback
                    console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                };

                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
        }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
    }, errorHandler.bind(null, fileName));
}

writeToFile('example.json', { foo: 'bar' });
```

Error:

```
Error in Success callbackId: File681009815 : SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input:312

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input:314

Error in Success callbackId: File681009817 : TypeError: Illegal constructor:312

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor:314
```

Any idea about what is wrong with the code?

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're testing this on Android 4.x. I've had the same problem on Android 4.2.2.

First of all, comment out the try{}catch{} from `platforms/android/platform_ww/cordova.js` lines 289,312-314, to know the exact line where your code fails. It'll probably be in `var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });`

Try out to write data directly to FileWriter without `Blob()`:

### with blob

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
fileWriter.write(blob);
```

### without blob

```
fileWriter.write(data);
```

The native api writes a String, so as long as you write text it should work:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/src/android/FileUtils.java#L1129

Also, I would check if the data you're trying to write is correct, mainly by this error:

> Unexpected end of input

And finally, probably this solution is related to this problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302872/1786341